# IOS: UITextField+UITableView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

I am new in iOS. I am making a chat application so I have a `UITextField` below the `UITableView` and `UITextField` and `UITableView` are inside the `UIScrollView` (I have disable the scroll in scrollview by `self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;`).
When I tap on `UITextField`, the keyboard was shown, so I move the `UITextField` to above keyboard follow [Managing the Keyboard doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

```
   // Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
    - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
    {
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

        // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
        // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
        CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
        aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeField.frame.origin) ) {
            [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.activeField.frame animated:YES];
        }
    }

    // Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
    - (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
    {
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }

    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        self.activeField = textField;
    }

    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        self.activeField = nil;
    }
```

With this code, my `TextField` move to above keyboard successful
**But the problem** is: In the `TableView`, when the keyboard was shown I cannot scroll to see some items on top (about 2 items).
For example, if my tableview have 10items, when the keyboard was shown, i can only see 8items, 2 rest items still exist but I cannot scroll to them

Here is my [Demo Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_poNaia6t8kV0xTT1RQSXplTWc)
I think maybe the content inset of `UITableView` is wrong but I don't know how to fix it.
Any help would be great appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use `Autolayout` insteads of `contentInsets`

In **ViewController.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *botConstraint;
```

In **ViewController.m**

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    self.botConstraint.constant = kbSize.height;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    //...
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    self.botConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    //...
}
```

`botConstraint` is `UITextField`/`UITableView`/`UIScrollView` `.bottom` = `fatherView`.`bottom` in your `Main.storyboard`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can you explain more about `botConstraint`. current, i add the `botConstraint` for my `UITextField bottom` and `UIScrollView bottom`. then when the keyboard was show, the textfield will appear on top of keyboard, and I can scroll all item in my `TableView`.
It seem like solve my problem. BUT a big problem is, during the keyboard show, the `TextField` don't slide with keyboard, `TextField` only appear after keyboard show.
And when keyboard shown, tableview don't animate anything, I want when keyboard shown TableView also slide to top.
Please guide me which I missing

Comment: Update your question code so i can see what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have include the demo project in my post. if you don't mind, can you check it. I just change only change my code like your code